# Trouble embedding a QComboBox in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a GUI using QT, and I'd like to have the final entry in my table be a combo box. The idea is to allow the user to chose new items to put in the table from a drop-down list.

What I seem to be having trouble with is embedding this combo box inside a table cell. I've tried this:

```
      table_widget = new QTableWidget(1, 9, Dialog);
      table_widget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("table_widget"));

      add_part_combo = new QComboBox(table_widget);
      add_part_combo->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("add_part_menu"));
      add_part_combo->addItem(QStringLiteral("Import New Items..."));
      table_widget->setCellWidget(1, 1, add_part_combo);
```

If I construct the combo box with `Dialog`, it puts the combo box in the upper left corner of the dialog (somewhat *under* the table). If I instead construct it with `table_widget`, the combo box appears in the upper left of the table (on top of the first header cell). If I don't supply a parent widget, then it doesn't appear at all.

But in no circumstance does the widget actually appear in cell 1,1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row` and `column` parameters passed to `setCellWidget` are zero-indexed.  Also, you don't need to provide a parent for the `QComboBox` since the `QTableWidget` will assume ownership of it when you call `setCellWidget`.  As such, your code should be as follows:

```
  add_part_combo = new QComboBox;
  add_part_combo->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("add_part_menu"));
  add_part_combo->addItem(QStringLiteral("Import New Items..."));
  // Note: Row and column 0, not 1.
  table_widget->setCellWidget(0, 0, add_part_combo);
```

Comment: Dang it, I looked really hard through the Qt docs I had to find language saying whether those numbers were 0 or 1 based, and couldn't find anything. Since they weren't going out of their way to tell me, I figured it was probably 1-based like Motif and MFC. :-(